# Kubuntu 17.10 & Nvidia driver = sluggish keyboard

Tags: drivers, nvidia, keyboard, kubuntu, kde

After filing a KDE bug report about the compositor flaking out, it was recommended I use the official Nvidia drivers instead of Nouveau. Now my windows are fine, but my keyboard input is lagged and sluggish. Does anyone have a guess on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but had a similar issue with lagging keyboard when switching from Nouveau to Nvidia drivers and this worked for me.

Did you blacklist the Nouveau drivers and then update initramfs? after that don't forget to reboot.

sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

add the following at the bottom of the page

```
# This is to remove the nouveau driver which conflicts with nvidia
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

sudo update-initramfs –u

sudo reboot

Comment: Tried all that. No difference. I'm currently running drivers from the "Padoka" PPA with no lag. I was able to recreate it from a fresh install of Kubuntu and the latest "approved" and packaged drivers from Ubuntu, v384. Moving to v390 from NVIDIA's site made no difference. I ended up purging NVIDIA and going with the open-source drivers instead.